# Unexplainable recalculations across tabs

Tags: excel, excel-2010, user-defined-functions, volatile, vba

I want to make a workbook in which calculations and tasks are defined in the first tab and all of the other tabs copy these calculations. Processing of the copied calculations should take place in the target tabs. I have three UDFs:

```
Function IsFormula(cell_ref As Range)
Application.Volatile
    IsFormula = cell_ref.HasFormula
End Function

Function ShowF(Rng As Range)
Application.Volatile
    ShowF = Rng.Formula
End Function

Function MyEval(s)
Application.Volatile
    MyEval = Evaluate(s)
End Function
```

The first Tab is called 'Definitions', the second 'Dion', the third 'Michel'. Now this is what I use to copy the calculations:

```
=IF(Definitions!C5<>"";IF(IsFormula(Definitions!C5);myeval(Showf(Definitions!C5));Definitions!C5);"")
```

It works. Now comes the funny part.

Say I want to just use the SUM formula. I add it in the Definitions Tab and it works in the Dion Tab. I can fill multiple cells (say C10=3, C11=4, C12=5) in a column and it adds up the values (12). Now when I switch to the Michel Tab, I see the same value (12) but of course no values in C10, C11 and C12 since I never put any values there. Where does '12' in the Michel Tab come from???

But it gets funnier. When I put values in the cells in the Michel Tab (C10=30, C11=40, C12=50), it changes the value of 12 to 120. Correct. Now I switch back to the Dion Tab, 12 changes to 120 too!! And of course C10, C11 and C12 are not modified there.

Is this behaviour to be expected?

Please send me a message if you want to have a copy of the Excel sheet. I can imagine that you would want to see it to understand it.

Cheers,
Martijn

I have Office Professional Plus 2010, Excel version 14.0.7128.5000

Comment: please add some screenshots

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Evaluate` takes its context from the `ActiveSheet` - that's why all your formulas return the same value. If you hit F9 you can see them re-evaluate to the activesheet's data.

If you want to evaluate *in the context of the sheet containing the formula* then try this fix:

```
Function MyEval(s)
Application.Volatile
    'MyEval = Evaluate(s)
    MyEval = Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate(s)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a bit more information. The suggested function does not work however, I get #VALUE! in all the cells that call the function. Also, F9 works for the active Tab, but it changes the values on all the other Tabs with it.

Comment: In my testing the change to include the parent sheet context worked: I can't tell what's different about your situation.  Are you talking about using F9 with my example, or with your original code?

Comment: I used F9 with my original code. Essentially, F9 does exactly what 'Application.Volatile' does, but then manually, at least in my sheet. Do you know of a way to manually recalculate the active tab and nothing but the active tab? That could be a work around...not great, but hey...

Comment: I do believe your second suggestion is the way to go, however, it does not work. I'll try to find out what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: Ok, when I strip it to =myeval("=SUM(C11:C16)") then it returns #VALUE!. C11 to C16 contain integers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by my second suggestion - I only had one (use the worksheet version of `Evaluate` in place of `Application.Evaluate`) .  F9 was just another way to show the problem with your original code.

Comment: Sorry about that Tim, I meant the change to 'Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate(s)' instead of 'Evaluate(s)', I saw that as your second suggestion. Thanks so far, appreciated!